# Poner varias galerías en una página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poner varias galerías en diferentes modal. El primer modal con la galería funciona perfecto pero los otros no abren, y cuando regreso al primer modal, encuentro la imagen abierta de otro que no se pudo abrir.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var time = 400;//set time
 // storing src attribute in empty array
 var arrayImages = [];
 // push all src attribute in array
 $('.thumb_gallery').each(function(){
  var attrSrc = $(this).attr('src');//'<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '">'
  arrayImages.push(attrSrc);
 });
 var firstItem = arrayImages[0];// taking first item in array
 var lastItem = arrayImages[arrayImages.length - 1];// taking last item in array
 var htmlImg1 = '<div class="container_img"><div class="closebtn">&#x2715;</div><div class="con-ac-ar"><span class="previousImage">&#x276C;</span><img class="activePopUpImg" src="'
 var htmlImg2 = '"><span class="nextImage">&#x276D;</span></div>' 
 //function openPopUpImage
 function openPopUpImage(){
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayImages.length; i++){
   var attr_src = $(this).attr('src');
   if( arrayImages[i] == attr_src){
    $('#background_overlay').html( htmlImg1 + arrayImages[i] + htmlImg2);
    $('#background_overlay').fadeIn(time);
   }
  }
 }
 // next Image function
 function nextImage(){
  var currentImage = $('.activePopUpImg').attr('src');
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayImages.length; i++){
   if(currentImage == arrayImages[i] && currentImage !== lastItem){
     $('#background_overlay').html(htmlImg1 + arrayImages[i+1] + htmlImg2);
   }
  }
 }
 // previousImage function
 function previousImage(){
  var currentImage = $('.activePopUpImg').attr('src');
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayImages.length; i++){
   if(currentImage == arrayImages[i] && currentImage !== firstItem){
     $('#background_overlay').html(htmlImg1 + arrayImages[i-1] + htmlImg2);
   }
  }
 } 
 // open image
 $('.thumb_gallery').click(openPopUpImage);
 //close image
 $(document).on('click', '.closebtn', function(){
  $('#background_overlay').fadeOut(time);
 });
 //next Image
 $(document).on('click','.nextImage', nextImage);
 //previous Image
 $(document).on('click', '.previousImage', previousImage);
 //keyboard  
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {//arrow left key
   previousImage();
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39'){//arrow right key 
   nextImage();
  }else if(e.keyCode == '27'){// esc key
   $('#background_overlay').fadeOut(time);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumb_gallery {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb_gallery:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

#background_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container_img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 600px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  animation-name: zoom_image;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

.con-ac-ar {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
/*para los certicales */
.con-ac-arVER {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.closebtn {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activePopUpImg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*para los certicales */
.activePopUpImgVER {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.previousImage, .nextImage {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.previousImage {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 600px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nextImage {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 600px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.previousImage:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nextImage:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
 @keyframes 
zoom_image {  from {
transform: scale(0.5)
}

to { transform: scale(1) }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 1100px) {

.container_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.con-ac-ar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.activePopUpImg {

  height: 500px;
}

.previousImage, .nextImage { line-height: 500px; }
}

/*para los certicales */
 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 1100px) {

.container_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.con-ac-arVER {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.activePopUpImgVER {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.previousImage, .nextImage { line-height: 500px; }
}




@media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 649px) {

.container_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.con-ac-ar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.activePopUpImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.previousImage, .nextImage { line-height: 400px; }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {

.container_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.con-ac-ar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.activePopUpImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.previousImage, .nextImage { line-height: 300px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="galeria">
                  <img class="thumb_gallery" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0eO.jpg" alt="Image Caption">
                  <img class="thumb_gallery" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0eO.jpg" alt="Image Caption">
                  <img class="thumb_gallery" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0eO.jpg" alt="Image Caption">
              </div>
              <div id="background_overlay">
              </div>
```

Comment: Yo lo veo bien, las tres imágenes se abren correctamente (nota: después de añadir jquery al fragmento de código). No es ese el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Hola! Mariano como mencionaba la una galeria funciona perfectamente el problema esta cuando intento abrir las otras no dan.

Comment: Amigo qui te dejo la pagina para que veas el comportamiento que tiene. http://turismolp.com/prefinal/